# JavaScript Statements Flagged as Not a Function?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have an JavaScript if..else statement inside of a block to hide or show two buttons:

```
/* Toggle Revert or Complete buttons based on order status */

if (!status1 || status2 == "wc-completed" ) { // Status check working
  (function() {
    $(document.getElementById(idDIVOrder)).querySelector('form.complete-order-cred').style.visbility = "hidden";
    $(document.getElementById(idDIVOrder)).querySelector('form.revert-order-cred').style.visbility = "show";
  })();
} else if (!status1 || status2 == "wc-processing" ) {
  (function() {
    $(document.getElementById(idDIVOrder)).querySelector('form.revert-order-cred').style.visbility = "hidden";
    $(document.getElementById(idDIVOrder)).querySelector('form.complete-order-cred').style.visbility = "show";
  })();
} else {
  console.log("Hide or display buttons not working! Order has a status of " + status1 + " and " + status1);
}
```

I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).querySelector is not a function", which also occurs if I place the `.querySelector` statements inside the `if` and `else` without functions.

What's the right way to declare JS functions here?

Comment: remove `$`. It's  `jQuery` selector. You can use directly `.querySelector`

Comment: That's because you're calling `$()`, which presumably is jQuery's `$()`, and jQuery objects don't have `querySelector`. I suggest either using jQuery, or not using jQuery, but not this mix. Also note that there's no point at all to those IIFEs in the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the resulting node from `document.getElementById()` in a jQuery object and then calling `querySelector()`? Just remove the jQuery wrapper, and that should work. I'd suggest taking a step back from what you're doing to think about what you're trying to achieve, and then re-writing your approach to that problem.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input! You'll have to excuse my silly mistake. The statements themselves don't work, however. Not really sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is a native DOM manipulation function, you are trying to call it on a jQuery object, which does not have this function.

You're going to want to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) here, or just forego jQuery altogether.